# When i try to run query to find the total count for sesison create in single day for 30 days

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'us.sessions'
which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause
```

Query which i am running to finding the session count day wise for one month.

```
SELECT
    us.sessions, us.avg_duration, us.sessions_date
FROM
    user_master um
        INNER JOIN
    user_institution_mapping uim ON um.id = uim.user_id
        INNER JOIN
    user_sessions us ON (us.user_id = um.id)
WHERE
    um.status = '1' AND uim.status = '1'
        AND uim.institution_id IN (26)
        AND us.sessions_date >= '2018-09-24'
        AND us.sessions_date <= '2018-10-25'
        AND uim.permission = 'all'
        group by sessions_date
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: I dont see  you **counting** no of sessions in a day

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya's probably right, but for further consideration, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct query for above error

```
SELECT sessions_date , SUM(sessions)
FROM
    user_master um
        INNER JOIN
    user_institution_mapping uim ON um.id = uim.user_id
        INNER JOIN
    user_sessions us ON (us.user_id = um.id)
WHERE
    um.status = '1' AND uim.status = '1'
        AND uim.institution_id IN (26)
        AND us.sessions_date >= '2018-09-24'
        AND us.sessions_date <= '2018-10-25'
        AND uim.permission = 'all'
        group by sessions_date
```